# How do you launch URL by opening an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I have the following scenario in my company:

- We have two BI tools
- One is a highly interactive reporting platform that reports from and generates
  the company data warehouse
- The other is SSRS which we use for our static form type reports. We
  also use it for real time reporting as this sources directly from the
  transactional databases

It is a hassle to have users jumping between two reporting platforms to find specific reports they are looking for.

What I would like to do is use SSRS as the home for all reports by creating dummy reports in SSRS whose only purpose is to redirect the user the report in other reporting platform

I imagine this should be possible using custom code functionality in SSRS.

What code (VB.net / C#) can I use to invoke a URL when a user clicks on the report.

Answer (score 1):

Add a textbox to your report with whatever text you want the user to see (e.g. My Other Report).

Right-click the textbox and choose properties, then click the Action tab

Select "Go to URL" and then set the URL as required.

Comment: Thanks. This is certainly one way of doing it: via actions. I'm really hoping I can get a solution that won't require a second click.

Comment: Oh, so you want to basically redirect. I mis understood. You could reduce the issue by having an index report. Users open that, see a list of reports from "other other system" and click the links. Not exactly what you wanted but maybe a reasonable compromise.

Comment: Yes that's also another possibility. Thanks again for another potential workaround.